# Erro ao usar EF6 CodeFirst com Mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou com o seguinte erro quando rodo o Migrations:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver? Estou com tudo devidamente instalado. Segue meu `Web.Config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ProjetoCultContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"   connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;Initial  Catalog=ProjetoCultContex;uid=root;pwd=******;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

E a configuração do Entity Framework:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory,   MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"    type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: @Cigano, pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Vou verificar aqui. Desculpe a demora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei vários problemas na sua configuração. Mude sua *connection string* para:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="NortaoCultContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;Database=NortaoCultContex;uid=root;pwd=********;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

A configuração do Entity Framework:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Abra o **Package Manager Console** e digite:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

O Visual Studio irá gerar o arquivo `Migrations\Configuration.cs`. Altere o construtor para:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }
```

Experimente gerar uma *Migration* para testar a configuração:

```
PM> Add-Migration Inicial
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra ter um melhor entendimento. Já tendo feito as alterações que sugeriu na sua resposta, porém o erro ainda persiste. Subi o projeto no [Github](https://github.com/Renancp01/ProjetoCult). Pra caso seja útil na resolução. Agradeço desde já .

Comment: @RenanCarlos Seu projeto tem uma série de problemas. Vale mais a pena começar um do zero e não seguir tutorial de DDD. Não complique o que não precisa ser complicado.

Comment: do que explicou acima, eu troquei um detalhe na connection string. Substitui o _Initial Catalog_ por _Database_

Comment: @RenanCarlos É mesmo. Alterei a resposta.